# Only allow specific people to download app from google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have made an Android application and am interested in only allowing specific people to download it from the Google Play store.

In an ideal world I would upload my app to the play store, and also upload a list of email address' of users who were allowed to see and download the app, which I would be able to edit at any time.

So far I have found a few possibilitys:

1. **Sending out the App via email.**  - Not ideal as the users will have to select the allow apps from unknown sources, the app is designed for non-technical people so this may worry them, also its a hassle I don't want people to have to do.
2. **Play store private channels** - Not everyone will be a user in the same domain as me so this is not an option
3. **Licensing the application**   -   I have read through the overview documentation which states it checks if the user has paid for the app. But this could also be used for free apps. Could this be used to check if the user email matches a list of emails?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to implement a login system for your app, using Google App Engine or whatever.  You can't restrict an app's visibility on Google Play based on emails.

Comment: Good call on the login system, but we already have a login system of sorts on the app

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at beta testing. it is supported by google +.

http://www.androidcentral.com/android-central-app-update-beta-testing-moves-google-community